# RAILS_ROOT require?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, directory-structure, constants, require

I'm trying to access the RAILS_ROOT constant in a file residing in the /lib directory, but I'm not able to (uninitialized constant error). Is there something that I need to require to be able to do this?

Comment: You don't have to include `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment.rb'`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you should require the environment.rb:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment.rb'
puts RAILS_ROOT
```

And `Rails.root` instead.

Comment: I get this error when trying to install Redmine, but I don't understand the answer. :( Where do I have to do what? "Require"?