# Rails.root in lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do i access the variable 
`RAILS_ROOT` 
or 
`Rails.root` 
in the /lib directory. For some reason i get variable not found error.

EDIT: I tried adding

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment.rb'
```

to the top of my file as recommended here [RAILS_ROOT require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933225/rails-root-require) but it still gives me `undefined method root`

Any idea, Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the actual line of code + the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAILS_ROOT is deprecated, try Rails.root instead.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment.rb')
 => "/home/lpeabody/Documents/ccom_work/dataserver31/config/environment.rb" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment.rb')
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 > Rails.root
 => #<Pathname:/home/lpeabody/Documents/ccom_work/dataserver31> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > RAILS_ROOT
NameError: uninitialized constant RAILS_ROOT
    from (irb):7
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: the path ended up being my problem

Comment: I had an inkling that might have been the issue, glad you're all set.